# Ruby on Rails Performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, html, rendering, jsonp

i'm currently working on a backend for a HTML5-Mobile Game. We use JSONP to communicate with the app (because of cross domain policies).

But the hosting on heroku is realy slow, we have an average response time of 900ms. I'm already using includes to speed up database access and a production database. 
I'm also running new relic to analyse the server.

Most of the time is used in the Controller itself. 650ms of 800ms are needed in the  Controller method.

```
Category     Segment    % Time   Avg calls
(per txn)    Avg 
time (ms)
Controller   TasksController#update  63.4    1.0     650
```

It is correct, the controller is doing much things, but is it possible, that some ruby code costs so much time? Or could it be something with jsonp returning stuff?

Newrelic tells me, that our user wait up to 5 sec for a response. That's realy a lot!

Our ApplicationController looks like the following:

```
# encoding: utf-8
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  include ApplicationHelper

  include ProfilesHelper

  before_filter :authenticate, :set_locale

  after_filter :check_for_kpi


  def check_for_kpi
    if (params[:kpi])
      case params[:kpi]
        when Hash
          params[:kpi].each do |k, v|
             #all done in delayed jobs
             Kpi.delay.add(k, :value => v)
          end
        when String
          Kpi.delay.add(params[:kpi])
        when Array
          params[:kpi].each do |k|
            Kpi.delay.add(k)
          end
        else
          logger.warn("Parameters for Kpi not detected. #{params[:kpi]} ")
      end
    end
  rescue
    logger.warn("Something went wrong in the check for kpis. ")
  end

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def authenticate
    authkey = params[:session_key]

    @error = {}

    @profile = Profile.includes(#some more includes).find_by_authkey(authkey)
    if (@profile.nil?)
          render_json(
              {
                  :authentication_error => true
              }
          )
    else
      if (params[:version]!= @profile.version)
        @profile.delay.update_attributes(:version => params[:version])
      end
    end

  end

  protected

  def render_json(json, profile = nil)
    profile ||= @profile
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {
        render :js => build_result_string(json, profile, params[:controller], params[:callback])
      }
      format.json {
        render :json => json.merge(profile.try(:getSessionData))
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Have you any ideas how to improve performance here?

Thanks!

Comment: I used to have a similar problem that when first trying to connect to the app it took around 3 seconds to load a homepage, then after that it was pretty fast. The problem was that often times we didn't have enough people accessing the site so heroku would switch off the server if it wasn't accessed for an hour and then it would take a couple of seconds to switch it back on, after which it was reasonably fast to use the app. Try using your app and see if you find that to be the same problem?

Comment: Hello alalani,No thats definetly not the Problem. We do have about 20 rpm on 2 running dynos. That's pretty enough to prevent the Heroku server from going down...